# Why is javascript closing page tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple js that outputs html based on a vendors variables

```
if (icAnalytics == "1"){//Analytics
    $("#anal22").html("<a class='test1 test2 test33' href=/dashboard/site_sum.asp?id=application>Analytics</a>");
        };

if (icPermissions >= "1"){//Publishers
            $("#pub22").html("<a tabindex='0' href=/admin/default.asp class='ubermenu-target ubermenu-target-with-icon ubermenu-item-layout-default ubermenu-item-layout-icon_left'><i class='ubermenu-icon fa fa-lock'></i><span class='ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text'>Pub</span></a>");
            }

if (icPermissions == "2"){//Admins
        $("#admin22").html("<a class=aTop2 href=/system/default.asp>Admin</a>");
        }

else {
 };
```

The problem is when I had the html to a "li" - so `<li id="pub22">` it automatically closes the "li" even though I haven't added that code into it.  I can't really change the layout of the page as I don't have access to it.  Is there a way to keep the li from closing after inserting the html from javascript?

Note - This is a little bit more complex.  The pub22 li is the first and then the anal22 and admin22 are nested and have different perms.  Since they are nested I wanted to leave the li open.  Maybe I am making this too hard.

Comment: What is your use case for inserting a partially formed element onto the DOM?  Why would you not fully create the node before applying it to DOM?  You should probably also get in the habit of being consistent in how you write HTML in javascript strings.  I would sugget the (more or less) industry standard way of using double quotes around element attributes and single quote for the actual string in javascript.

Comment: @MikeBrant - This is for a vendor website that I am putting in the html that dynamically reflects if someone is admin or not based on js variables.  Everything is working except for closing the li tag.

Comment: @blankip That still doesn't answer the question of WHY you would want to insert something like `<li id="pub22">` (which is not a a valid element by iteself) into DOM.  Why not add the `</li>` as well?

Comment: @MikeBrant - I added a note.  The other html I need to add is nested in that li.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you add any HTML to the DOM with JavaScript, the web browser is going to try to parse that HTML. If you create an `<li>` element without closing it, the browser is gonna be like "whoa, that's not valid HTML; I'll just fix that" and it'll automatically close the tag.

But all hope is not lost! Instead of adding code to the DOM as you write it, store it all in a string and only add the string to the DOM once you're done with it.

Here's an example:

```
var myHtml = "<li>"
myHtml += "blah blah this is some content";
myHtml += "</li>";
$("#someElement").html(myHtml); //we add the html to the DOM only now that we're done writing it
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do something like:

```
$element = $('<li id="pub22">...</li>');
$element.append('<a id="anal22" href="...">...</a>');
$element.append('<a id="admin22" href="...">...</a>');
$element.appendTo('#someContainerElement');
```

Here you create your `<li>`, append a few `<a>` elements to it, and then finally attach the `<li>` to some existing element in the DOM.  Creating elements in this way and attaching them to DOM when you are ready to make active is one of the key features of jQuery (in fact this is part of the base jQuery function).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.html` uses JavasScript's `.innerHTML`

`.innerHTML` inserts nodes into the DOM. A node, by definition, has to be valid markup. So the browser is correcting your bad markup on the fly.

Comment: I added a note about this being nested.  If I could add the entire script in I would.  However the other two variables are nested in this.  So when it closes it kills the dropdown menu.

Comment: @blankip that's an issue with your logic, rather than `.html` though. This is working exactly as designed. What you need to do is do all your nesting *before* you inject it into the DOM as oxguy3 points out.

Comment: Of course.  But if I could use logic I would let php parse my admins.  The fact is, I am not changing the structure of the vendor's code for their menu.    I have created a lot of js that adds html to vendor sites and I guess this is the first time I have had a nesting issue pop up.